# What helps us carry things around?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction, everyday-life, free-body-diagram

Say I move from point A to point B. I carry an apple in my hand. What causes the apple to move from point A to B? In other words, what force is responsible for keeping the apple stuck to my hand and accelerate with the same acceleration as me? Is it friction or normal reaction?

What is the work done by each? Please mention the sign too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puk is correct, but I'd like to elaborate on his answer a little bit. If you just place the apple on your hand (and don't grip it), the friction from your hand is responsible for moving the apple. Let's assume that you, your hand, and the apple are moving to the right.

Now think of it this way: when the hand begins moving, the apple is not moving. So, if you think the hand as your reference frame, you could think that the apple was *trying* to move to the left, and therefore there will be a static friction which will oppose this, facing in the *opposite* direction (to the right).

This static friction is what causes the apple to stay on the hand as you continue moving.

Lastly, adding to Puk's answer about the net work, if you stop moving (and the apple stops moving), the net work you did will be zero. This is because when you initially begin to move, you accelerate the apple by applying a positive force in the right direction. This force multiplied by the positive distance it travels *while* this force is being applied is the work done during this period. But then, when you slow down to a stop, you're applying a static force in the negative/left direction, so the work done would be this negative force multiplied by still a positive distance moved during this deceleration. They work done during acceleration and deceleration would then cancel out, making the net work be zero.

Answer (score 3):

The normal force is always at least partially responsible. Without the normal force, there is no friction. To what extent friction and normal force separately play a role depends on how you hold the apple. If you grip it tightly, it is likely mostly the normal force keeping it moving with you. If you place it on the palm of your hand that is facing upward, the net force due to friction as the apple accelerates/decelerates is likely significantly greater than the previous case.

Assuming the apple has the same height and speed at B as it does at A, no net work has been done on the apple. It is possible that a positive work has been done by the normal force and negative work by friction, and vice versa. This again depends on how you carry the apple.

Answer (score 2):

It's the friction. Also, the thought that it "accelerates with the same acceleration as you" is false. It certainly has inertia, and it will fall if you move with too much acceleration. but your assumption applies with velocity, without no acceleration. So basically, it's like this.

[image: The forces of the apple.]

If the apple has mass $m$, it will have a normal force of:
$$N=mg$$
and the friction will be:
$$f=-\mu N = -\mu mg$$
This is on the backward direction. However, because of newton's third law(The apple certainly can't move your hand, can it?) The apple is pushed forward with the same amount of force.
$$f=\mu N = \mu mg$$
And the work done by friction can be calculated as:
$$W=Fs=fs=\mu mgs$$
So, There you have it!

Comment: This calculation is with the assumption that you lay your hand flat and put the apple just on your hand. If you grab the apple, however, forces on the hand will directly affect the apple, making the calculation much harder.

Comment: That's one ugly picture.

Comment: @Andrej I agree, I do need to get a drawing tablet.